# When the same class has 2 versions, how to make sure version#1 is picked?

Tags: java, gson, classloader

Concretly, I copied gson's ObjectTypeAdapter class into my project, with below change (line 78):

From

```
        case NUMBER:
            return in.nextDoulbe();
```

To

```
        case NUMBER:
            String s = in.nextString();
            if(s.contains("."))
                return Double.valueOf(s);
            else
                return Long.valueOf(s);
```

Now this class is defined both in gson-2.8.1.jar and my.jar.

Per my tests, this works as expected, the one in my.jar is picked, and number is not always parsed as double now.

The problem is how to make sure my version will be **always** picked? Or not possible?

Comment: Do you also use the same package name for your version of the class?

Comment: There are programmatic ways to trick the class loader to do that, however, this approach is error prone. It would be much better to redefine the class in a different package or provide a differently named facade to work with that. Or, if you really want to replace it: fork the gson library, replace the class and include your own library as a whole.

Comment: Yes must be the same package otherwise it will not be called. But I can't replace the whole lib.

Answer (score 0):

First on classpath was the rule. With several class loaders that already could pose some difficulties (like app server libraries). But in java 9 your trick is likely to work no longer.

So make your custom TypeAdapter.

First I tried to extend, but as `ObjectTypeAdapter` is a final class (thanks @Leon), on could use delegation to an ObjectTypeAdapter.

```
public class MyObjAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Object> { 
    private ObjectTypeAdapter delegate = new ObjectTypeAdapter();

    @Override public Object read(JsonReader in)
            throws IOException {
        JsonToken token = in.peek();
        switch (token) {
        case NUMBER:
            String s = in.nextString();
            return s.contains(".") || s.containsIgnoreCase("E")
                ? Double.valueOf(s)
                : Long.valueOf(s)   
        default:
          return delegate.read(in);
        }
    }        ...
}

GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder(); 
builder.registerTypeAdapter(Object.class, new MyObjAdapter()); 
Gson gson = builder.create();
```

Comment: It's final, you can't extend it.

Comment: @Leon altered the answer. In fact if you had the source, picking an other package path would do too.